# SQL MIN() selecting Data. ORDER table correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 questions. First of all I have a *MySQL* Database with the rows: **id(AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)**, **name** and **time**. This database represents the times of a race. I would like to select the name and time where the time is the smallest.

```sql
SELECT name, MIN(time) as time FROM race GROUP BY TIME;
```

This query gives me all times and names as long as there are no duplicates in the names. I however only want the fastest time and the name in that row.

Then when I submit my time i would like to know on what place I am. Will `ORDER BY TIME` keep each ID of each row the same or can I just ORDER table BY time and then select row where ID= 1?

Comment: Your query is not correct! Are you sure it runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's possible to have multiple entries with the same time, I would use a nested query like this, because limiting the result set to 1 may exclude a name.

```
select name, time from race where time = (select min(time) from race)
```

If you want to know what place a given time is in, just count the number of entries that have times less than it.

```
select count(*) + 1 as place from race where time < [your time]
```

Comment: See my edit for the second question. A count query will do it.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, what you want is to select the 'least' time.

Here is, what I think, the clearest way to do that, which uses the LIMIT function to only return 1 row.

MySQL:

```
SELECT name, time 
FROM race 
ORDER BY time asc
LIMIT 1;
```

MS SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, time
FROM race
ORDER BY time asc
```

Comment: Why did you add the SQL-Server variation?

Comment: Since I work with both, and I see examples of C#, Android, and PHP usage of SQL queries everywhere, I often get confused on the differences in MySQL and MS SQL syntax. I like to know when they are different. If you come across a query that uses SELECT TOP 1, and you're a MySQL developer, at least you know how to do it in MySQL.

Comment: works but only returns one name in case of duplicate times. thanks a lot though!